# Validar en PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy en una base de datos PL/SQL y necesito armar un script anónimo para insertar en una tabla de configuración (campos config y value). Algo como esto:

```
Config: ‘country’       Value: ‘Argentina’
Config: ‘moneysign’     Value: ‘$’
Config: ‘dateformat’    Value: ‘DD/MM/YYYY’
```

El problema es que necesito validar que las 3 inserciones sean correctas y además, en caso de falla, se debe identificar cuáles fallaron y dejar la base en el estado consistente anterior al inicio del script anónimo (según tengo entendido se hace con *ROLLBACK* o algo similar).

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puesto que PL/SQL es un lenguaje orientado a transacciones, entonces puede englobar esas tres inserciones dentro de una transacción. Es decir:

```
DECLARE
  …
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mi_table (campo_1, campo_ 2)
      VALUES('country', 'Argentina');
  INSERT INTO mi_table (campo_1, campo_ 2)
      VALUES('moneysign', '$');
  INSERT INTO mi_table (campo_1, campo_ 2)
      VALUES('dateformat', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || ' :''( ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

---

Para saber más:

- [Excepciones en PL/SQL](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/48/Excepciones-en-PLSQL.aspx)
- [Transacciones en PL/SQL](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/articulos/63/Transacciones-con-PLSQL.aspx)
- [Exception PL/SQL parte I - tratamiento de errores a fondo](http://deletesql.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=438).
- [Exception PL/SQL parte II - tratamiento de errores a fondo](http://deletesql.com/viewtopic.php?t=437).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo todo en una misma transacción y en caso de excepción al insertar cualquiera de los valores de configuración se capture y haga un rollback. De este modo solamente se guardará la transacción si todos los registros se han insertado satisfactoriamente

```
BEGIN
  --
  SAVEPOINT SP_CONFIGURATION;
  --
  INSERT INTO CONFIGURATION(config, value) VALUES ('country', 'Argentina');
  INSERT INTO CONFIGURATION(config, value) VALUES ('moneysign', '$');
  INSERT INTO CONFIGURATION(config, value) VALUES ('dateformat', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  --  
  COMMIT;
  --  
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  --
  ROLLBACK TO SP_CONFIGURATION;
  --  
END;
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción sobre qué hace este código. Lee **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código hace uso de un cursor con los datos de interés y, mediante un **FOR LOOP**, controla la inserción de datos. Si un registro falla, la variable *v_CodeResp* cambia su valor y al final no realizará el **COMMIT**. En su lugar realiza un **ROLLBACK**, regresando el estado de la tabla a como estaba antes de ejecutar el bloque anónimo.

¡Saludos!

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_CodeResp INTEGER := 0;
    v_MsgResp  VARCHAR2(300);
    v_Log      VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FOR Datos IN (
            SELECT 'Country' AS CONFIG,  'Argentina' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'moneysign' AS CONFIG, '$' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'dateformat' AS CONFIG, 'DD/MM/YYYY' AS VALUE FROM DUAL)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TABLA(A, B) VALUES(Datos.CONFIG, Datos.VALUE);

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            v_MsgResp := 'Fallo al insertar: '|| Datos.CONFIG || ' ' || Datos.VALUE ||' ';
            v_Log := v_Log || v_MsgResp;
            v_CodeResp := 1;
    END;
END LOOP;

IF v_CodeResp <> 0 THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
    v_MsgResp := 'Registros insertados correctamente';
    v_Log := v_Log || v_MsgResp;
END IF;



DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Log);
END;
```